# How to put round borders on a TH without getting the sharp corner?

Tags: css

Trying to make my table look nice, but I cannot get rid of those sharp corners...

[image]

Here is the HTML

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="expense-table-pink">
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #bb1133;">
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>bbb</th>
        <th>ccc</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS

```
.expense-table-pink {
    width:100%; 
    background-color: #f9ecee;
    border: 1px solid #bb1133; 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;    
    font-weight: normal;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of border pixels vs. corner pixels. In this case, increasing the `border` to `2px` fixes this issue:

```css
.expense-table-pink {
    width:100%; 
    background-color: #f9ecee;
    border: 2px solid #bb1133; 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;    
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="expense-table-pink">
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #bb1133;">
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>bbb</th>
        <th>ccc</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I first tried rounding the corners inside the `th` but that just created a gap, but your solution actually worked - I just have to live with the border being 2px all around :-)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Happy to help buddy. It's all a matter of math, "hiding" the corner edges" requires a thicker border.

Answer (score 2):

This is that pointed red thing you are seeing,

```
style="background-color: #bb1133;
```

The accepted answer does not solve the issue completely because what if you really need border to be 1px such as in this case. Why increase the border when you can do something like this,

```
table { border-collapse: separate; }
tr:first-child th:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 5px; }
tr:first-child th:last-child { border-top-right-radius: 5px; }
```

This solves the border-radius issue without changing border itself which needed to be 1 px. Make border-radius of th corners to 5px to leave no gaps. My answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for the left and the right corners...

CSS

```
.thleft {
   border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.thright {
   border-radius: 0 6px  0 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<th class="thleft">aaa</th>
<th>bbb</th>
<th class="thright">ccc</th>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/uwe335b3/)

Comment: I believe that if you change the border-radius for 50% of the external border-radius.... this will be solved... in this case 3px...